# How do I deploy a specific revision of my puppet code with r10k?

Tags: puppet, r10k

Using r10k to deploy my puppet code. How do I use it to deploy a specific revision? Specifically, my :base repo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you use git repository:

A particular commit

```
mod "network",
  :git => 'git://github.com/example42/puppet-network.git',
  :ref => 'deb120e'
```

A particular tag

```
mod "zabbix",
  :git => "git://github.com/dj-wasabi/puppet-zabbix.git",
  :ref => '1.3.0'
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking more about :base than modules, but that is good to know as well!

Comment: What do you mean by `:base`, @catpants?